# Eliminating taking of breath

Tags: adobe-audition, breathing

I am recording my voice in an environment with a machine that is creating a noise with relatively constant amplitude and frequency. In all the recording of my voice in this environment, this noise is present.

This noise, I can eliminate satisfactorily by the following procedure:

1 - Capture the sound for at least 20 seconds to collect a sample.

2 - Select this sample through `Capture Noise Print`

3 - I completely select my audio track and eliminate the noise using the sample through `Noise Reduction (process)`

I know this procedure and I have no problem with that.

**The question I have is the following:**

In brief excerpts from my speech, I take a breath to start a new sentence. And this breaths are bothering me.

I thought about applying the same procedure I applied to the room's constant noise.

But by applying this procedure, my breathing sample distorts my voice by becoming somewhat robotic.

I am eliminating the breath visually and silencing manually.

Is there anything in Adobe Audition CC‎ that does this mapping?

Comment: [Waves DeBreath](https://www.waves.com/plugins/debreath#removing-vocal-breaths-with-debreath) can do it live, but I've never tested it on an already noise-reduced track, nor do I know if it works in Audition though I'd assume so. Might be worth testing the demo.

Comment: You might have some results using a gate, if you low-pass the detector input (say at 1kHz or above). That way, the gate will only trigger on sounds that have low frequency content, which will include most consonants and all vowels. You might have trouble with fricatives like 'f' but with enough tweaking of low/high pass and threshold, you should be able to find a workable configuration. I'm sorry I'm not familiar with the specific plugins available in Audition, but it should have that functionality.

Comment: @Tetsujin Great tip

Comment: while all the comments and answers are great, i wouldn't recommend doing this. Debreathers bring anxiety to the listener and make the overall experience unpleasant. This though , is from the listener standpoint. If your breathing is too bass-y maybe cut some lows , or highs if it's too treble-y , but de-breathers sound really bad. If you are not making a commercial video with patched / edited talking parts , i'd suggest keeping your breaths and just eq to have more voice over them (or less breath as stated above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @Tetsujin, there are a few plugins I've heard of:

- [Waves DeBreath](https://www.waves.com/plugins/debreath#removing-vocal-breaths-with-debreath)
- [iZotope Breath Control](http://help.izotope.com/nectar2/content/nectar%202%20help%20documentation/breath%20control%20plug%20in.htm)

Maybe even more?! Anyway, they should do the job quite well.

A gate can help as well, but it is strongly depending on the volume ratio of breath signal and desired speech signal. Sometimes, breathing is strong (especially for singing voice), and a gate can affect your voiceless fricatives, like [f], [‎ç], [s] or [S]. It can also affect the soft decay of a voice.

However, my procedure is to **manually fade-in** to breathing, as this keeps the desired, naturally appealing amount of breath. Of course, the more breath events you have to deal with, the more likely a plugin will be plausible.